# Which Python modules provide good foundation classes for spatial data?

Tags: python, spatial

I am preparing to build an application in Python that works with a lot of spatial data.  I am looking for a Python module that provides a nice set of spatially-enabled classes that I can inherit from.  Two things I would like to have baked in are:

- Support for both vector and raster data, and conversions between both formats.
- Support for projecting coordinates between datums.

The best module I have been able to find so far is [shapely](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely/1.2.7) but it focuses on vector data and does not include support for datum transformations.  An example of the kind of library I am looking for is the [sp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/index.html) package for R which provides classes for holding both vector point data and dense or sparse raster data along with datum transformation support.

Are there any Python modules that provide a nice set of spatially enabled classes that I may be overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More precisely: Shapely is about planar computational geometry and nothing more. It's not a vector data library at all. I use it with Pyproj (http://code.google.com/p/pyproj/). I haven't come across any Python foundation classes for geospatial. They abound, of course, in Java projects like GeoTools. Python arrays could be a good starting point: arrays of coordinates can be used by Shapely and raster-like arrays can be used by GDAL. You might also take a look at the GeoJSON-ish interfaces provided by Shapely, ArcPy, and the SimpleGeo APIs.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it describes what seems to be the current state of Python spatial libraries: there are currently no foundation classes for geospatial objects.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try the Geospatial Data Abstraction Library?

I found it on Linux where its called *python-gdal*.

Abstract of Debians GDAL:

> GDAL supports 40+ popular data formats, including commonly used 
>    ones (GeoTIFF, JPEG, PNG and more) as well as the ones used in
>    GIS and remote sensing software packages (ERDAS Imagine,
>    ESRI Arc/Info, ENVI, PCI Geomatics). Also supported many remote
>    sensing and scientific data distribution formats such as HDF,
>    EOS FAST, NOAA L1B, NetCDF, FITS.
>
> OGR library supports popular vector formats like ESRI Shapefile,
>    TIGER data, S57, MapInfo File, DGN, GML and more.

[see on trac.osgeo.org](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython)

Comment: The GDAL library does provide the functionality I need, but the raw SWIG bindings are not at all pythonic.  I am currently building a new set of classes over GDAL and Shapely---which is what I was hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all Python modules are listed at the [CheeseShop](http://pypi.python.org/) so start there. I can't find anything obvious, though.

Answer (score 0):

RSGISLib is a suite of command line tools with python bindings for processing remote sensing/spatial data in both vector and raster format, which you may find useful.

The link to the webiste is http://www.rsgislib.org and it can easily be installed using Anaconda